# How to display video on web server with http?(tcp socket programming-file transfer to server in c)

Tags: c, sockets, http

I'm trying to transfer the file which Client requests with URL like

http://localhost:10080/test.mp4

I have to receive most of file types which are normal for web.
For image, txt, html, pdf it successfully displays files on web.
I should also display video (not download) but I can't.

[#1]

my HTTP Header is :"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n"

this give me message which includes this line: 
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/jxr, * / *(no whitespace!)

when I tried [#1], cracked words

ex)�U��D�}�r�mU�~嶼V!�H:y⒦XR

appears. I guess it may need some encoding..?But not sure.

[#2]

changed HTTP Header to:"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type :video/mp4\r\nContent-Length :99999999999\r\n"

For [#2], download message appears on web, and its size is same with that I set in Content-Length in HTTP header, not the real size of the mp4 file. It keeps asking download even when I delete Content-Length.

How can I display video file on web using http, tcp?

If you want to view code only about file upload, please search this(Sorry but it keeps make Error when I tried to shorten):

char* file_name = get_filename(client_msg);

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
////server.c

int file_exists(char* filename) {
    FILE* file;
    if (file = fopen(filename, "rb")) {
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }
    return -1;
}

int isthere_params(char* msg) {
    //index.html
    if (msg[5] ==' ') return -1;
    //log in
    else if (msg[5] == '?')
        return 1;
    //file request
    else return 0;
}
char* get_filename(char* msg) {
    char * parsed_name = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*2050);
    int i,idx=0;
    for(i=5; i<2050; i++) {
        if (msg[i] == ' ') break;
        parsed_name[idx++] = msg[i];
    }
    return parsed_name;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int* login_flag = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
    *(login_flag)=0;
    int len,is_params, server_socket, client_socket, client_addr_size, client_msg_size;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr, client_addr;
    char client_msg[10000], buf[4100];
  char rsp_packet[2048]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n";
  //char rsp_packet_copy[2048]="HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type :video/mp4\r\nContent-Length :99999999999";
    char _403_packet[1024] = "HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden\r\n\r\nYou dont't have permission to access ";
    char _404_packet[1024] = "HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found\r\r\r\rFile is not found";

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage : %s <port>\n", argv[0]);
        return -1;
    }

    server_socket = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(atoi(argv[1]));
    //bind
    if (bind(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)) == -1) {
        puts("bind error!");
        return -1;
    }
    //listen
    listen(server_socket, 10);

    //enter the loop
    while(1) {
        puts("wait to accept.... \n");
        client_addr_size = sizeof(client_addr);
        client_socket = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, &client_addr_size);
        if (client_socket == -1)
            puts("fail to accept client connection! ");
        //receive from client
        if ((client_msg_size = recv(client_socket, client_msg,100,0)) > 0) {
            printf("%s \n\n", client_msg);
            //is_params 1:OK -1:Entrance url 0:file input
            is_params = isthere_params(client_msg);
            printf("isparams!----->%d\n", is_params );
            printf("\n\n login flag-->%d \n\n",*login_flag);

            if (is_params == -1) {
                send(client_socket, rsp_packet,strlen(rsp_packet),0);
                int fr = open("index.html",O_RDONLY);
                if (fr <0) {
                    puts("Error(index)");
                    exit(1);
                }
                while ((len=read(fr,buf, 4096)) > 0 ) {
                    send(client_socket,buf,len, 0);
                }
                close(fr);
            }
            else if (is_params == 1) {
                send(client_socket, rsp_packet,strlen(rsp_packet),0);
                *(login_flag)=1;            
                int secret = open("secret.html",O_RDONLY);
                if ( secret<0) {
                    puts ("Error(secret)");
                    exit(1);
                }  
            while ((len = read(secret, buf, 4096)) >0) {
                    send(client_socket,buf,len, 0);
                }               
            }   

            else if (is_params == 0) {
                //when failed to login
                if (*login_flag == 0)
                    send(client_socket, _403_packet, strlen(_403_packet),0);
                else {
                    char* file_name = get_filename(client_msg);
                    if (file_exists(file_name)== -1) {
                        send(client_socket, _404_packet, strlen(_404_packet),0);
                    } else {
                        send(client_socket, rsp_packet,strlen(rsp_packet),0);
                        int fr = open(file_name,O_RDONLY);
                        if (fr <0) {
                            puts("Error(file)");
                            exit(1);
                        }
                        while ((len=read(fr,buf, 4096)) > 0 ) {
                            send(client_socket,buf,len, 0);
                        }
                        close(fr);
                    }
                }
            }
            //Send the message back to client
            //write(client_socket, client_msg, sizeof(client_msg));
        }
        close(client_socket);
    }//end while

    close(server_socket);

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Go through all you code and fix all the instances where you call a library function that requires a NUL-terminated char array with an argument that is not guaranteed NUL-terminated, eg: 'printf("%s \n\n", client_msg);'

Comment: Then go through all your code and  fix all the instances where you make a system call like send() without correctly and completely handling the value returned.